# How to divide secured and unsecured area using Spring Security login

Tags: spring-mvc

My current Spring MVC application was initially designed to accommodate only authenticated users, thus to use the application users will navigate to `www.myappdomain.com`. However now I would like to migrate these resources under `www.myappdomain.com/member` and use the previous one as a static web site (or accessible by anybody).

One solution that I can think of is to modify all controllers with `RequestMapping("member")` but this also requires me to modify all mapping in JSP.

Is there any other way that is more convenient to achieve what I want ?

**UPDATED**

Based on the answer given by M. Deinum I decided to create additional servlet name. However, each time I try to login (with or without correct credentials) I get redirected to the login page.

*web.xml*

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>site</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>site</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/member/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/member/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

security-context.xml

```
<http pattern="/**/favicon.ico" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/**/resources/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/maintenance.html" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
        disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/login*" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            login-page="/member/login" authentication-failure-url="/member/loginFailed" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <session-management
            session-authentication-error-url="/member/loginFailed">
            <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
                max-sessions="1" />
        </session-management>
        <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>
```

*login.jsp*

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>"
            autocomplete="off">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="username"><spring:message code="label.username" />
                    <span class="ico"><img src="${imgPath}/user.png"
                        alt="Username Icon" border="0"></span></label> <input type="text"
                    name="j_username" id="username" required autofocus> <label
                    for="password"><spring:message code="label.password" /> <span
                    class="ico"><img src="${imgPath}/pass.png"
                        alt="Password Icon" border="0"></span></label> <input type="password"
                    name="j_password" id="password" required>
            </fieldset>
            <c:if test="${!empty errorMsg}">
                <div class="errorMessage">
                    ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}</div>
            </c:if>
            <fieldset>
                <button type="submit">
                    &gt;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <spring:message code="label.go" />
                </button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

*DEBUG TRACE* generated once I press the submit button in my login form.

**org.springframework.web**

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'app' processing GET request for [/dnag2/member/login]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /login
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.dnag2.controller.AuthenticationController.initLogin(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/dnag2/member/login] is: -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'login'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'app'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'login'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

**org.springframework.security**

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/member/j_spring_security_check'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/member/j_spring_security_check'; against '/**/resources/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/member/j_spring_security_check'; against '/maintenance.html'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/member/j_spring_security_check'; against '/member/login*'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/member/j_spring_security_check'; against '/member/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /member/j_spring_security_check; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@2d4d3ce6. A new one will be created.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: FACD6A03C058DB14AFEE4FF7BAF6A1FA; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /member/j_spring_security_check at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/member/j_spring_security_check'; against '/member/login*'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/member/j_spring_security_check'; against '/member/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /member/j_spring_security_check; Attributes: [isFullyAuthenticated()]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: FACD6A03C058DB14AFEE4FF7BAF6A1FA; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@72ffa2f5, returned: -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Is the static and dynamic content in the same war file?

Comment: yes. Would it be better if I separate them ?

Comment: No, just needed to know... See my answer.

Comment: Post your login form. My guess is that submits to '/j_spring_security_check', however it should submit to '/member/j_spring_security_check', due to the fact that the filter listens to urls starting with '/member'

Comment: It submits to `/member/j_spring_security_check` and says it found. I checked this through the network tab in Chrome.

Comment: Enable debug or trace logging for `org.springframework.security.web` and see why it gets redirected. Probably something to do with your spring security setup.

Comment: I tried to add `<intercept-url pattern="/member/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"
   requires-channel="https" />` into my security-context.xml. That addition gave me `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/dnag2/member/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'app'` error during form submission.

Comment: Either your form isn't submitting right or the output you posted isn't the output from the form submit (it is a GET to /login, which looks like the initial page render). This is also the output of the normal web and not from spring security, can you add that. Also is your `springSecurityFilterChain` still mapped to `/member/*` or to `/*`? I assume it still is `/member/*`.

Comment: the output occurs during the redirection to the login page after form submission. The `springSecurityFilterChain` is still mapped to `/member/*`.

Comment: Can you add the output for org.springframework.security, enable debug/trace logging for that. There must be something in the spring security config that is causing this. (I'm wondering in the rendered form what the action url is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is in a single war and you don't want to modify the controllers simply add another `DispatcherServlet` to your web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>member</servlet-name>
    // Other properties
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>member</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/member/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This servlet contains/loads all the dynamic controllers, where as your current servlet will serve and handle all the static content. You might need to restruce your configuration a little.

When using multiple `DispatcherServlet` instances and when Spring Security is mapped to only one of them (in this case /member/*), remember to configure the `<form-login .. />` element properly. You need to add the attribute `login-processing-url` so that it will properly match the login url. By default that is '/

```
<form-login login-processing-url="/member/j_spring_security_check" ... />
```

To make it work inside the filter mapping.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. However each time I try to login I get redirected to the login page. I am updating my question with the xml files. Thanks

Comment: In the configuration for your `DispatcherServlet` mapped at /, make sure that you enable `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` and ofcourse that you have configured Spring Security correctly (it should be mapped at a url-pattern of /* not to a servlet).

Comment: My static content is able to be viewed. It's just the restricted area is unable to be accessed accordingly. Will do as what you suggested and come back to you with the update.

Comment: perhaps you want to update your answer with your last comment on `login-processing-url`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your second `intercept-url` to only include the members path. Like this.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/members/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https" />
```

**Update**

As this is generally very straight forward to implement in Spring, I took your security-context and simplified it. Try this. Once it is working, you can add back some of the additional options:

```
<http pattern="/**/favicon.ico" security="none" />
<http pattern="/**/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/maintenance.html" security="none" />
<http pattern="/member/login**" security="none" />

<http pattern="/member/**" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()"
        requires-channel="https" />

    <form-login 
       authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
       login-page="/member/login" 
       authentication-failure-url="/member/loginFailed" 
    />

    <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```

Comment: I tried both `/member/**` and `/**` but it still give the `org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied` error.

Comment: Hmm... did you try this: `<http pattern="/members/**" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">`.

Comment: after using that I get this error `WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/dnag2/member/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'app'`

Comment: I am still getting the access is denied error on the spring security log

Comment: What is the url you are calling?

Comment: Looking at your logging output the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` isn't processing the URL. Add `login-processing-url="/member/j_spring_security_check"` to your `form-login` element. The default is `/<context-root>/j_spring_security_check', you need to force that to '/<context-root>/member/j_spring_security_check'. Or map the filter to /* and let the form submit to '/dnag2/j_spring_security_check'

Answer (score 0):

Use  `<sec:http pattern="/member " security="none" />`